# NSPredicate for searching a string with double quotes

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, predicate

An attribute element in coredata model is a string(json string format), which is an array of dictionaries like below,

one element has

```
"[{"tagName":"sad","count":2},{“tagName":"happy","count":1}]"
```

and other has

```
"[{"tagName":"sad1","count":2},{“tagName":"happy1","count":1},{“tagName":"nothappy","count":1}]"
```

Need to search the list with refer to the tagname.

If I use the predicate below,

```
tagName = "sad"
tagNameFilter += String(format: "vrTags CONTAINS[cd] \"%@\"", tagName)
```

it's returning both elements. It should return the first element alone

If I use without double quotes

```
tagName = "sad"
tagNameFilter += String(format: "vrTags CONTAINS[cd] %@", tagName)
```

it's crashing with reason:

```
unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (vrTags CONTAINS[cd] sad) (LHS and RHS both keypaths) with userInfo of (null)
```

If I use

```
tagName = "sad"
tagNameFilter += String(format: "vrTags CONTAINS[cd] \"\"%@\"\"", tagName)
```

it's crashing with reason: `Unable to parse the format string`

How to solve this filter issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: ```tagString CONTAINS[cd] "\"sad\""```

Comment: @vikingosegundo, edited the question, please check now, need to pass the value dynamically. still crashing.

Comment: Why do you save tags as json in core data? Why not have a proper entity `Tag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to search for a string `"sad"` including the quotation marks you have to pass that string *with the quotation marks* as an argument to `NSPredicate(format:)`. This can be done with with string interpolation:

```
let tagName = "sad"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "vrTags CONTAINS[cd] %@", "\"\(tagName)\"")
print(predicate) // vrTags CONTAINS[cd] "\"sad\""
```

And *never* use `String(format:)` and string concatenation to build complex predicates. That is very error-prone because the quoting and escaping rules for predicate strings are different from those to format strings.

If you need to combine multiple conditions with “AND” then do it like

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(...)
let p2 = NSPredicate(...)
// ...
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p1, p2, ...])
```